# Query the _id of a document in MongoDB

Tags: java, html, mongodb, jsp

I wanted to find a document by using the object id. However, there is no result even though the object id was correct. This is my java code.

```
ObjectId id = (ObjectId)request.getParameter("id");
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("source");
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("_id",id);
```

I believe I need to change something at the    whereQuery.put().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the String `id`, you need to pass the `ObjectId`, e.g.:

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("_id",new ObjectId(id));
DBObject result = collection.findOne(query);
```